# Delphi TListBox OnClick / OnChange?

Tags: delphi, onclick, subclass, onchange, tlistbox

Is there a trick to getting "OnChange" type of functionality with a TListBox? I can subclass the component and add a property, etc then only carry out OnClick code if the Index changes... I can also hack it with a form level variable to store the current index but just wondering if I'm overlooking the obvious before I go one way or the other.

Comment: What do you mean by that `OnChange` type functionality ? Content change, selection change, combination of it, something else ?

Comment: @TLama "... if the **Index** changes ..." ;o)

Comment: There is no OnChange event for TListBox only OnClick. Basically if you are using OnClick and click in the control, but not on an item, it still fires the OnClick event which can retrigger code unless you are also tracking the previously selected index. What I'm looking for is probably against the control design, but more like a TComboBox in list form.

Comment: The `OnClick` event (in this case it is quite confusing name) is fired whenever the user selects an item by mouse or keyboard, but not when you set it in code through `ItemIndex` property (which you may bypass by overriding `SetItemIndex` method and calling `Click` from there).

Comment: OnClick appears to fire if you click anywhere in the listbox... you do not have to actually click an item. It also fires if you click an item that is already selected. So I only want the OnClick to fire if an actual item that is not the previous item or the listbox itself is selected. I.e. emulation of an OnChange event.

Answer (score 13, accepted):

There seems to be no way other than implementing this by yourself. What you need is to remember the currently selected item and whenever the [`ItemIndex`](http://docwiki.embarcadero.com/Libraries/en/Vcl.Controls.TCustomListControl.ItemIndex) property is changed from code or whenever the control receives the [`LBN_SELCHANGE`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/desktop/bb775161%28v=vs.85%29.aspx) notification (which currently fires the [`OnClick`](http://docwiki.embarcadero.com/Libraries/en/Vcl.Controls.TControl.OnClick) event), you will compare the item index you stored with item index which is currently selected and if they differ, fire your own `OnChange` event. In code of an interposed class it could be:

```
type
  TListBox = class(StdCtrls.TListBox)
  private
    FItemIndex: Integer;
    FOnChange: TNotifyEvent;
    procedure CNCommand(var AMessage: TWMCommand); message CN_COMMAND;
  protected
    procedure Change; virtual;
    procedure SetItemIndex(const Value: Integer); override;
  published
    property OnChange: TNotifyEvent read FOnChange write FOnChange;
  end;

implementation

{ TListBox }

procedure TListBox.Change;
begin
  if Assigned(FOnChange) then
    FOnChange(Self);
end;

procedure TListBox.CNCommand(var AMessage: TWMCommand);
begin
  inherited;
  if (AMessage.NotifyCode = LBN_SELCHANGE) and (FItemIndex <> ItemIndex) then
  begin
    FItemIndex := ItemIndex;
    Change;
  end;
end;

procedure TListBox.SetItemIndex(const Value: Integer);
begin
  inherited;
  if FItemIndex <> ItemIndex then
  begin
    FItemIndex := ItemIndex;
    Change;
  end;
end;
```

Comment: thanks... I was thinking of deriving a new component but didn't consider interposing.

Comment: if (AMessage.NotifyCode in [LBN_SELCHANGE, LBN_SETFOCUS]) and (FItemIndex <> ItemIndex) then ...

Answer (score 0):

with the OnClick event is just like this...you need to store the last value to compare it.

```
if ListBox1.Items[ListBox1.ItemIndex]<> Edit1.Text then
    Edit1.Text := ListBox1.Items[ListBox1.ItemIndex];
```