# How to display TStringList items in a MessageBox

Tags: delphi

I can't figure this out...

Display the TStringList (A1,A2,A3) items in an InputBox.

also, I have tried to use

> function InputCombo2(const ACaption, APrompt: string; const AList:
>   TStrings): string;

but this function does not work

```
var
List: TStringList;


 if Not FileExists(CradTypeText)
 then
     Begin
      List := TStringList.Create;
      List.Add('A1');
      List.Add('A2');
      List.Add('A3');
         repeat
              CardTypeStr := InputBox('Card Recharger', 'Please select the card', List);
         until (CardTypeStr = 'A1') or (CardTypeStr = 'A2') or (CardTypeStr = 'A3');
         //ShowMessage(iStr);//Test
         AssignFile(myFile, CradTypeText);
         ReWrite(myFile);
         WriteLn(myFile, CardTypeStr);
         CloseFile(myFile);
         List.Free;
     End
  Else
      Begin
          IDEdt.Enabled := False;
          AssignFile(myFile, IDtext);
          Reset(myFile);
          ReadLn(myFile, CardTypeStr);
          IDEdt.Text := CardTypeStr;//Test
      End;
```

Comment: `ShowMessage(StringList.Text);` ?

Comment: @TLama i want the user select one of the items then he click OK button  if he close the window or he click on cancel button the window will repeat until he chose an item

Comment: @TLama selecting one of the items shows as combo box

Comment: Until you understand what you want to do it is pointless asking a question. How can we tell you how to do something if you don't understand it enough to describe it?

Comment: @DavidHeffernan Excuse my English language

Comment: Your English is fine. You need to explain the problem better. Please can you edit.

Comment: `InputBox`, `InputQuery` does not show *selectable* items. You have to design your own form.

Comment: None of the dialogs shown with InputBox, InputQuery, or MessageBox display lists and accept a user selection from them. Your question as written makes no sense. If you want the user to select items from a listbox or combobox and click a button, design a form that displays the list and allows them to make a selection.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

A dialogbox like the one shown using `MessageBox`, `InputBox` etc are simply precooked forms.

You want to add extra item to them you'll have to design your own form.

Here's how to do this:

**Adding an extra form to your project**

Add an extra form to your project: File -> New... -> Form

Drop a ComboBox or ListBox onto the form (I prefer the listbox).
And drop two Buttons.

Set the following properties:

```
Button1.ModalResult:= mrOK;
Button2.ModalResult:= mrCancel;
```

This form will be your dialog.

**Customize the dialog so it can hold options to display**
Add a public property to the form like so:

```
TForm2 = class(TForm)
private
  FOptions: TStringList;
  FChoosenOption: string;
  ....
public 
 property Options: TStringList read FOptions write FOptions;
 property ChoosenOption: string read FChoosenOption;
 ....
end;
```

Assign the following code to the OnShow event of the form:

```
procedure TForm2.Form2Show(Sender: TObject);
var 
  i: integer;
begin
  if Assigned(FOptions) then begin
    ListBox1.Items.Clear;
    for i:= 0 to FOptions.Count -1 do begin
      ListBox1.Items.Add(FOptions[i]);
    end; {for}
  end; {if}   
end;
```

Store the selected item when to user selects it.

```
procedure TForm2.ListBox1Click(Sender: TObject);
begin
  self.FChoosenOption:= ListBox1.Items[ListBox1.ItemIndex];
end;
```

**Showing the form**
By default the form will be automatically created, which is fine.

The following code will do the trick:

```
procedure TForm1.BtnShowMeOptionsClick(Sender: TObject);
begin
  Form2.Options:= MyListOfOptions;
  case Form2.ShowModal() of
    mrOK: begin
      self.OptionPicked:= Form2.ChoosenOption;
    end;
    mrCancel: begin
      self.OptionPicked:= '';
    end;
  end; {case}
end;
```

Something like this should do the trick.

**Some info**
See: http://docs.embarcadero.com/products/rad_studio/delphiAndcpp2009/HelpUpdate2/EN/html/delphivclwin32/Forms_TCustomForm_ShowModal.html
[Delphi TListBox OnClick / OnChange?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/20889016/delphi-tlistbox-onclick-onchange)